# Select N elements from each row without looping

Tags: python, numpy

Given a `numpy` array `items` of of shape `(D, N, Q)` and another array of indices `ids` of shape `(N, P)`, how can I make a new array `my_items` of shape `(D, N, P)`, by using the indices `nq_ids`, like the following:

```py
# How can these loops be avoided?
my_items = np.zeros((D, N, P))
for n in range(N):
    for p in range(P):
        my_items[:, n, p] = items[:, n, ids[n, p]]
```

with `numpy` magic instead of using any explicit loops? Here is a minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np

D, N, Q, P = 2, 5, 4, 3  # Reduced problem dimensions.
items = 1.0 * np.arange(D * N * Q).reshape((D, N, Q))  # Example data
ids = np.arange(0, N * P).reshape(N, P) % Q  # Example ids

# How can these loops be avoided?
my_items = np.zeros((D, N, P))
for n in range(N):
    for p in range(P):
        my_items[:, n, p] = items[:, n, ids[n, p]]

# print('items', items)
# print('ids', ids)
# print('my_items', my_items)
```

I would also like to preserve the element order if possible.

Comment: `items[np.arange(D)[:,None,None], np.arange(N)[:,None], ids] `

Answer (score 0):

This should work now, returning the exact same ndarray as your loop:

```
np.stack([np.take(items[:,i,:], ids[i, :], axis=1) 
          for i in range(ids.shape[0])], axis=2).transpose((0,2,1))
```

However, @hpaulj's method is faster, by 23.5 µs vs 5 µs. So use that.